# Can't get alt to work as a prefix on tmux mac

Tags: terminal, tmux, macos

I'd like to get <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> to work, but it doesn't seem to work. This is how I have my `.tmux.conf`:

```
set-option -g prefix M-Space
```

I also tried <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> but this doesn't work either.

```
set-option -g prefix M-b
```

Maybe someone that has a Mac + `tmux` can help?

Comment: I think your answer lies here - https://superuser.com/questions/649960/option-key-does-not-work-as-meta-in-tmux.

Answer (score 1):

Terminal -> Preferences -> Profiles -> Keyboard and checking "Use Option as Meta key"